# Find $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\frac{2x\cdot arccos\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)-\pi x}{2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

It is indeterminate form $(\infty - \infty)$ in the numerator.

Could it be transformed to use L'Hospital's rule?

Answer (score 3):

By substituting $x=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$, then $\theta=\pi-\varphi$,
$$\begin{eqnarray*}\lim_{x\to +\infty}-x\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\right)&=&\lim_{x\to +\infty}-x \arcsin\left(\frac{2x}{1+x^2}\right)\\&=&\lim_{\theta\to \pi^-}-\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\arcsin(\sin\theta)\\&=&-\lim_{x\to \pi^-}(\pi-\theta)\tan\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)\\&=&-\lim_{\varphi\to 0^+}\varphi\cot\left(\frac{\varphi}{2}\right)\\&=&\color{red}{-2}.\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 1):

You could first divide by 2 and than factor out x:
$$x[\arccos(\frac{2x}{1+x^2})-\frac{\pi}{2}]$$
Now substitute $x = \frac{1}{u}$ and change the limit to $ u \rightarrow 0$. You will get 
$$ \frac{\arccos(\frac{2u}{1+u^2})-\frac{\pi}{2}}{u}$$
Then you can apply L'Hospital's rule.

[Edit] You could also expand arccos in a Taylor Series at x = 0. Convergence is no problem as the argument of arccos is $<1$ for sufficiently large x.

Comment: When applying substitution, doesn't $arccos$ should be $arccos(\frac{2}{u^3+u})$?

Comment: $\arccos(\frac{2/u}{1+1/u^2})$ if you now expand the fraction by multiyling $u^2$ to the numerator and denominator you will get $\arccos(\frac{2u}{1+u^2})$. Its really interesting, that this transformation leaves the expression unchanged.

Comment: Not really, as $2x/(x^2+1)=2/(x+1/x)$